# headless firefox with selenium (webdriver-manager) and se-interpreter

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

On an AWS Ubuntu Machine, I can not get [se-interpreter](https://github.com/Zarkonnen/se-interpreter) to run a test against a headless firefox running with Xvfb.

If I followed some basic install steps:

```
sudo su
npm install -g webdriver-manager
webdriver-manager update --standalone
npm install -g se-interpreter
apt-get install xvfb
Xvfb :10 -ac &
export DISPLAY=:10
firefox &
se-interpreter /home/ubuntu/test.json
```

Where test.json is any 'ol script generated from Selenium Builder.

All I see logged is:

```
SE-Interpreter 1.0.7
```

Thoughts on how to get this to work? The tool is based on https://github.com/admc/wd.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/brownman/json_wire_protocol

If you run **chromedriver**:
- port is: 9515
- the path is: '/'
- browser: chrome

if u run **selenium-server jar**:

```
cmd="./interpreter.js   --driver-host=0.0.0.0 --driver-port=4444 --driver-path='wd/hub' --browser-browserName=$browser $file2";  
echo $cmd  
eval "$cmd"
```